# Value folder name for different screen size android

Tags: android, layout, user-interface, size, screen

I am trying to support my application for all screen sizes. I'm able to do it to some extent but now facing issue for naming value folder for different screen sizes.
Device 1) 
    density [1.3312501]
    densityDpi [213]
    widthPixels[800]
    heightPixels [1280]
    xdpi [188.148]
    ydpi [187.93]

Device 2) 
    density [1.0]
    densityDpi [160]
    widthPixels[600]
    heightPixels [1024]
    xdpi [160.421]
    ydpi [159.568]

I'm using integer value from value folder for different screens like:
    170
    200

I gave the folder name as: value-sw600dp-mdpi && value-sw600dp
Problem is for both the devices values are picked from value-sw600dp-mdpi folder.

Please help me out in differentiating folder name for these targets.

Thanks a ton in advance !

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is for both the devices values are picked from value-sw600dp-mdpi folder.

That is what should happen.

> I gave the folder name as: value-sw600dp-mdpi && value-sw600dp

`res/values-sw600dp/` will never be used. Once you add a density qualifier, Android will elect to use one with a density qualifier (deemed the closest match to the device's actual density), to the exclusion of others that lack a density qualifier.

> Please help me out in differentiating folder name for these targets

Ideally, there is no difference for those targets, at least on density terms. `-tvdpi` (your first device, with the 213 density bucket) should not be special. I consider what you are trying to do to be a code smell, suggesting that you are attempting to use size and density buckets to achieve some measure of "pixel perfection" that they are not designed to support.

That being said, and assuming that you need the `-sw600dp` part for something else, `res/values-sw600dp-mdpi/` and `res/values-sw600dp-tvdpi/` will distinguish them.